# After fresh clone, git pull says up-to-date, push says there's remote work, browser shows files not present locally

Tags: git, bitbucket

EDIT 2: For some reason, one version of the repo on another computer was working. I pushed a meaningless change from there, and now everything else works too. I have no idea why. Not sure if I should delete this post or not now.

EDIT: This one is messy, trying to clean it up.

Basically: I have a freshly-cloned bitbucket repository. There are files I can see in the bitbucket browser interface that I do not have locally. If I try to pull, I'm told everything's up to date. If I try to push changes, I'm told the remote has work that I don't. Retracing my steps command by command:

```
git clone https://myname@bitbucket.org/myname/myrepo.git
Cloning into 'writing'...
remote: Counting objects: 5919, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (226/226), done.
remote: Total 5919 (delta 91), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (5919/5919), 183.62 MiB | 2.48 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (307/307), done.
Updating files: 100% (5658/5658), done.
```

At this point, there's a particular file that I can see in bitbucket's broswer interface that is not in my local repository.

```
git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Using `git log` the most recent commit is from March 10th; the browser interface shows one from yesterday. I've not made any branches for this repository, and the browser only lists "master".

I'm unable to push:

```
$ echo "ugh" -> ugh.txt
[$ git add ugh.txt 
$ git commit -m "ugh"
[master 31b845a] ugh
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 ugh.txt
$ git push
To https://bitbucket.org/myname/myrepo.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://bitbucket.org/myname/myrepo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

And fetch/pull does nothing:

```
$ git fetch
$ git pull
Already up to date.
```

Other commands/results:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://myname@bitbucket.org/myname/myrepo.git (fetch)
origin  https://myname@bitbucket.org/myname/myrepo.git (push)
```

Comment: Can you spot a difference in commits via git log, or a difference in local changes with git diff?
Did you try to just git fetch, instead of git pull?
Are you on the correct branch?

Comment: Update the question with the full list of command you ran and each's output.  From the clone to the push.

Comment: what does `git remote -v` return. Are the remote urls for `fetch` and `push` the same or do you see different urls for `fetch` and `push`

Comment: @simmue Yes, there is a commit I made/can see in the browser that git log does not show. `git diff` shows nothing. `git fetch` doesn't seem to do anything (no result, nothing behaves differently afterwards). There is only the master branch that I can see.

Comment: @D-Rock Did so (and re-did the steps to make a cleaner version)

Comment: @AsifKamranMalick `git remote -v` output eddited into OP (it shows the same for both). `fetch` and `push` show the same URL.

Comment: Could you try running `git pull --all`. If that doesn't pull in any possible new remote changes then try `git pull origin master:master`. Just give it a try.

Comment: There's no value in deleting the post. Leave that to the moderators.

Comment: @AsifKamranMalick Something weird happened... I went back to the computer I'd pushed yesterdays commit from, pulled and pushed from there, and pushed a meaningless change. After that I tried your `--all` thing and it worked, and then regular `pull` worked everywhere (every version of the repo on both computers.) Not sure if it was `--all` or pushing from the one local version. Either way it works now, but I'm very confused what happened and would appreciate any insight

Comment: `--all` just gets passed to `git fetch`, where it means *fetch from all remotes*. My best guess right now is that something was broken on Bitbucket. Big server sites like Bitbucket and GitHub have multiple "front end" machines that talk with customer requests and multiple "back end" machines that store repositories, and the front ends tend to have caches. If the caches get out of date with the real repositories, you get this behavior. They're not supposed to get out of date, but bugs happen.